# code to plot the qrs indexes on the ecg signal

Tags: plot

I have used the xqrs_detect from wfdb to find the indices of the QRS(idx_rr_txt). I also have the ecg signal which I plotted using the plt.plot(ecg_signal). I need to plot these QRS indices on the ecg signal.

I tried the below code. Seems to be wrong because of different dinmensions

```
idx_rr_txt = wfdb.processing.xqrs_detect(sig=sig_txt, fs=fs)
plt.plot(sig_txt)
plt.plot(sig_txt,idx_rr_txt,marker='o')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out

 `plt.plot(sig_txt)
 plt.scatter([idx_rr_txt], [sig_txt[idx_rr_txt]], c='r')
 plt.show()`

This does the trick.